# GMSPanoramaView convert to image

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-street-view

How I can convert Street View (`GMSPanoramaView`) to image? I haven't got any problem with normal map view. Here is code I used for maps:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
SaveMapForSyllabus *SMFSVC = [segue destinationViewController];
SMFSVC.image = mapImage;
```

After making image I'm passing it to another View Controller where image is saved. Also it's saving some image but it's only grey/black view with Google logo etc as seen on standard map/StreetView. It lost somewhere that panorama.

Comment: It's working when I'm using 1.6.1 version of Google Maps instead of current 1.4.3. But only 1.4.3 support iOS5 which is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem you are having.  I couldn't figure out how to convert it to an image, so eventually I came up with a make shift solution.  I wanted to be able to display these views as thumbnail images in `UITAbleView` cells.

The problem is you can't assign a `GMSPanoramaView` to the `cell.imageview.image` property.  While this may not directly answer your question, this solution is a viable work around and I hope it will help you.  I merely decided to overlay the `UITableViewcell`'s image with the `GMSPanoramaView`, setting its constraints and frames to be the same, adding it as a subview to the cell.  Here is my code.  This all happens in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImageAvailable"];

// Is this an actual UIImage or not?  If not, in my case it is a GMSPanoramaView
if ([[tableItem mapImage] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {

}else{
    // this will overlay over the no image available because we need
    // the image to stay there to enforce constraints since this view
    // isn't a true image and is just overlaying the cell image
    CGRect frame = cell.imageView.frame;
    UIView *viewToAdd =(UIView*)[tableItem mapImage];
    viewToAdd.frame = frame;
    NSArray* contraints = cell.imageView.constraints;
    [viewToAdd addConstraints:contraints];
    [cell addSubview:viewToAdd];
}
```